# How to figure out files without extension in a directory using python

Tags: python

I have some files in a directory without any extension and I was wondering how to search for this files out and add .txt as an extension to them?

Is there a better way to do this?

```
    for file in found:

          fileExt = os.path.splitext(file)[-1]
          if '' == fileExt:
              print 'Found No Ext %s' %file
```

Comment: You could use the `os.listdir("path/to/some/dir")` to get list of your files (http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and then rename them with `os.rename()`

Comment: List the directory contents with [``os.listdir``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir), split names and extensions with [``os.path.splitext``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext), rename files with [``os.rename``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename). See if you can solve your problem yourself now.

Comment: What Bogdan said. Documentation for the os.path family of functions here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html (assuming you are using python v2.7.5; if not there's a dropdown menu on that page to select a different version. I wouldn't expect radical differences between versions anyway.).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply [list](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.listdir) all files in the directory and then [rename](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.rename) them:

```
dirname = '/some/directory'
for f in os.listdir(dirname):
    path = os.path.join(dirname, f)
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        continue  # A directory or some other weird object
    if not os.path.splitext(f)[1]:
        os.rename(path, path + '.txt')
```